# AttributeError: can't set attribute - Python instance attribute assignment

Tags: python

I am encountering a strange problem that relates to instance attributes. I have a variable `logger`, which I want to be an instance attribute. However, I get the error `AttributeError: can't set attribute` **unless** I move the attribute `logger` outside the `__init__()` function, which (IIRC), means that I am declaring `logger` as a class attribute (not what I want).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class MyScraper(ABC,scrapy.Spider):
    """Abstract base class for scraping non JS Web pages"""
    #logger = None    # Commented out, as I don't want class instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
        self.topic = None            

        log_format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        log_level = 10
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("{0}.log".format(kwargs['log_filename']), when="midnight", interval=1)
        handler.setLevel(log_level)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add a suffix which you want
        handler.suffix = "%Y%m%d"

        #need to change the extMatch variable to match the suffix for it
        handler.extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{8}$") 

        self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger') # <- barfs here

        # finally add handler to logger    
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)   

        # Set up messaging infrastructure ...
```

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you create a get-function for self.logger? That might be a reason you cannot set it (without using a set-funtion that is).

Comment: @mrCarnivore (nice user name BTW!). I don't understand your question. I have other instance variables in my code, and the only one that raises this  AttributeError exception is the `logger` variable,

Comment: @property
def logger(self):
    return logging.getLogger('my_logger') (like in the answer below) would be a "get-function". With this you make a variable read-only. And therfore causing the error message (thanks for the user-name comment! :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2960c9b5683dceb149823e7f927d8c86ee83deb8/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L35) (or even if you just `print(scrapy.Spider.logger)` you can see that `Spider.logger` is a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), and in particular without a setter defined, so you can't easily assign to it.

You don't necessarily need to create your own logger if you want to add additional handlers though, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve beyond that.  Though if you ''really'' wanted to override the default `self.logger`, since you're subclassing `Spider` there's nothing stopping you from adding something like:

```
@property
def logger(self):
    return logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

to your class.

Comment: thanks, i also forgot that when i use `@property` then i need to move the `self.variable` to `self._variable` ... so i needed to assign `object._variable = "x"` and not `object.variable = "x"` ..